# Firebase initailize multiple app facing with reinitailize issue

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to initial two apps on NextJS frontend and backend (under /api route) respectively.
initializeApp works on frontend

```
const isAppExist = getApps().find(app => app.name === 'FE')
const app = !isAppExist ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'FE') : getApp('FE');
db = getFirestore(app);
```

But under /api route when I do

```
const isAppExist = await getApps().find(app => app.name === 'ADMIN')
const adminApp = !isAppExist ?
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
  }, 'ADMIN')
  : getApp('ADMIN');
```

Even isAppExist gives me undefined, admin.initializeApp() gives me error:

> Firebase app named "ADMIN" already exists.

Is this something to do with async? How do I solve this?

Firebase app named "ADMIN" shouldn't be already exists